# C#: How to convert decimal to string without converting to exponential representation

Tags: c#, object, decimal

For instance, I have an object array with some values. It can be decimal, double ,int or strings.
`object[] oo = {0.000278121, 0.000078125m, "Hello",1};`
For instance when converting this values to string, the second value becomes 7.8125E-05. But first value stays as in array. So how to differentiate parsing logic for that types, and parse all decimal values in the same format? Full code:

```
object[] oo = {0.000278121, 0.000078125,"Hello",1};
string[] ss = oo.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|",ss)); // 0.000278121|7.8125E-05
```

Comment: You can specify the format you want as a parameter to [Double.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2). By using `object[]` instead of `double[]` you don't allow your code to use `Double.ToString()` but only the limited `Object.ToString()` method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but there is no available parameter for ToString(). And also I read this object array from Excel file and not all values are decimal. So It is also necessary to check if it is convertable to decimal?

Comment: Another option is to use `String.Format("{0:...",x)` instead of `ToString()`

Comment: Could you cast the decimals in the object to doubles first? 

object[] oo = {(double)0.000278121, (double)0.000078125};

Comment: Those are not `decimal`, by the way, they are `double`.  If you want decimals, you need to suffix the number with an "m": `object[] oo = {0.000278121m, 0.000078125m};`  Any particular reason you are putting them into an array of object (other than a value type representation)?

Comment: Excel? That's another case then. If you use a library like EPPlus or the OpenXML SDK you can retrieve cell values as strongly typed text, doubles etc.

Comment: The reason that `ToString` doesn't take a format string is that you are using the call signature for `object.ToString` rather than using the more specific `double.ToString` or `decimal.ToString` (both of whom have overrides that take a format string).  Consider using a `decimal[]` or `double[]` or `List<decimal>` or `List<double>` for your `oo` variable

Comment: @JamesMorrison opposite problem. If they were decimals then the code here would work, but they're already doubles.

Comment: @Flydog57 I read values from Excel file. `var attributes = parsedRow.ItemArray.Skip(4).ToArray(); 
            var result = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Length; i++)
            {
                var attributeName = attributeNames[i];
                var attributeValue = attributes[i];
                result[attributeName] = attributeValue.ToString();
            }
            return result;` And attributes array is object []. That's why I can not convert. because there are also string values in file

Comment: `string[] ss = oo.Select(x => ((double)x).ToString("F9")).ToArray();`

Comment: Well, you didn't specify that.  If they are not all double (/decimal), then walk through the array and stringify differently based on type.  Most useful classes override `object.ToString()`.  Many provide an overload.  If you want to do different things to different types, you need to write code that does it

Comment: Edit your question.  Put that information in there.  You can have more than one code block.  If your array has more than one type in it, show that in your example: `object[] oo = {0.000278121, 0.000078125, "Hello World"};`

Comment: @Flydog57 Sorry for not clarification. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a disparate collection of objects, treat each type differently:

```
var outStrings = new List<string>();
object[] oo = { 0.000278121, 0.000078125, "Hello World" };
foreach (var ooItem in oo) {
    if (ooItem is double dOo) {
        outStrings.Add(dOo.ToString("0.#################"));
    } else {
        outStrings.Add(ooItem.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you have many types that you want to treat individually, use a pattern matching `switch` statement

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, that's not a `decimal`, it's a `double`. Use `0.000278121m, 0.000078125m` if you want `decimal`s.

To force a full length string representation without exponentials use `.ToString("0.#################")` for double. With decimal the default does this so `.ToString()` as you have would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of below line:

```
string[] ss = oo.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

You can use below line your code:

I am assuming that 10 is maximum number of decimal digits you can have in the input sets. 
If there are more then change N10 to some other number.

```
string[] ss = oo.Select(x => ((double)x).ToString("N10")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use double.ToString(string) method. See: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Double_ToString_System_String_

The parameter can be either custom numeric format strings (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) or standard numeric format strings (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2#NFormatString).

The precision specifier of "N" format specifier should be between 0 and 99 (N0 ~ N99), otherwise the ToString method will return the string passed as parameter instead. You could do `double.ToString("N99")`, which will return the string in numeric form in its highest precision. The problem with this is that if you do `0.000078125.ToString("N99")`, the output would have lots of trailing 0s, like: `0.0000781250000000000...`.

To overcome this, you could use string.TrimEnd(char) method. 0.000078125.ToString("N99").TrimEnd('0') will trim the trailing zeros, so the output can be 0.000078125.

In the given example code, this can be applied as:

```cs
//Avoid boxing - specify types whenever possible, or use generic
double[] oo = {0.000278121, 0.000078125};
string[] ss = oo.Select(x => x.ToString("N99").TrimEnd('0')).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|",ss)); // 0.000278121|0.000078125
```

Edit: I should have read the question more carefully, changing the type of `oo` would not be suitable in your case. However, the general idea is the same; Cast the object to double, Use ToString(string) method with appropriate precision, then trim the trailing zeros.

You can check that the type of object is double by doing `obj is double`, and furthermore, cast it back to double by `obj is double dbl` (Pattern matching).

Edit 2:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> AllToString(IEnumerable<object> objArray)
{
    foreach (object obj in objArray)
    {
        switch (obj)
        {
            case double dbl:
                yield return dbl.ToString("N99").TrimEnd('0');
                break;
            case bool b:
                yield return b.ToString();
                break;
            case int i:
                yield return i.ToString();
                break;
            case short s:
                yield return s.ToString();
                break;
            case string str:
                yield return str;
                break;
            case float flt:
                yield return flt.ToString("N99").TrimEnd('0');
                break;
            case decimal dcm:
                yield return dcm.ToString("N99").TrimEnd('0');
                break;
            case byte bt:
                yield return bt.ToString();
                break;
            case char ch:
                yield return ch.ToString();
                break;
            case uint ui:
                yield return ui.ToString();
                break;
            case ushort us:
                yield return us.ToString();
                break;
            case sbyte sb:
                yield return sb.ToString();
                break;
            case long ln:
                yield return ln.ToString();
                break;
            case ulong uln:
                yield return uln.ToString();
                break;
            case null:
                yield return null; //new string()?
                break;
            case DateTime dt:
                yield return dt.ToString();
                break;
            case TimeSpan ts:
                yield return ts.ToString();
                break;
            default: //Fallback
                yield return obj.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Pass the object array to the method, then call .ToArray() or .ToList() if required. This will convert every item in the array/list of object to a collection of strings.

Comment: Also, others have pointed out but numbers with decimal point denotes `double` literal. If you want it to be the literal of `decimal`, it must be followed by `m`, or if you want it to be `float` literal, 'f'.